# Circular buffer in C

Tags: c

I'm attempting to make a sort of circular buffer in C. Here is what I have right now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ORDER 3
#define LENGTH 7

short input[LENGTH] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
short buff[ORDER] = {0,0,0};
short pos = 0;

void filter(short input, short *buff, short *pos) {
    short p = *pos;       
    if (p==ORDER) {
        p=0;
    }
    p++; 
   *(buff+p) = input;
    printf("%d %d %d (%d)\n",*(buff+p),*(buff+p-1),*(buff+p-2),p);      
    *pos = p;    
}

void main() {
    short i;
    for (i=0;i<LENGTH;i++) {
        filter(input[i],buff,&pos);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
1 0 0 (1)
2 1 0 (2)
3 2 1 (3)
4 0 3 (1)
5 4 0 (2)
6 5 4 (3)
7 0 3 (1)
```

However, I'm trying to get it to output:

```
1 0 0 (1)
2 1 0 (2)
3 2 1 (3)
4 3 2 (1)
5 4 3 (2)
6 5 4 (3)
7 6 5 (1)
```

Basically the numbers are getting shifted over by one each time. I'm pretty sure I'm close but I can't seem to make this happen.

Comment: You have a few obvious problems...

1. *pos <-- you are dereferencing a short.. dont do that.
2. input <-- you have two of these.. lets try some new names.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior whenever `main()` calls `filter()` while `pos % ORDER == 0`, for then `filter()` ends up trying to evaluate `*(buff - 1)` as the last `printf()` argument.  This is an out of bounds array access.  It looks like these cases may be correlated with the misbehavior.

Comment: Oh, right.. John is correct. (I was just confused due to your naming.. pos was a pointer). This should probably fix it:  printf("%d %d %d (%d)\n",*(buff+(p%ORDER)),*(buff+(p+2%ORDER)),*(buff+(p+1%ORDER)),p);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void filter(short input, short *buff, short *pos) {
    short p = *pos;       
    if (p==ORDER) {
        p=0;
    }
   *(buff+p) = input;
    printf("%hd %hd %hd (%hd)\n", buff[p],buff[p-1<0 ? p-1+ORDER : p-1],buff[p-2<0 ? p-2+ORDER : p-2], p+1);
    //printf("%hd %hd %hd (%hd)\n",buff[p],buff[(p-1+ORDER)%ORDER],buff[(p-2+ORDER)%ORDER], p+1);

    *pos = ++p;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things a lot.  Try using the modulo operator instead of juggling pointers.

```
short pos = 0;
short buff[ORDER];

void filter(short input) {
    buff[pos] = input;
    short second = (pos - 1) % ORDER;
    short third = (pos - 2) % ORDER;
    printf("%d %d %d (%d)\n", buff[pos], buff[second], buff[third], p);
    pos = (pos + 1) % ORDER;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified down to this:

```
void filter(short input, short *buff, short *pos) {
    buf[*pos] = input;
    printf("%d %d %d (%d)\n",buff[*pos],buff[(*pos+2)%ORDER],buff[(*pos+1)%ORDER],*pos);
    (++(*pos)) %= ORDER;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just pass to filter a pointer to the input and the index you want to start at

```
void filter(short * input, short* pos){
    int i;
    for(i = *pos;i<ORDER;i--){
        printf("%d ",input[i] % ORDER);
    }
    printf("(%d) \n",*pos);
    *pos = (*pos + 1) % ORDER;
}
```

and call it like

```
filter(input,&pos);
```

Using a loop allows you to change the value of order at any point and print any range of values.